# Ubuntu Preseed and Templating

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04, debconf

I'm loading and executing this bash file from my preseed file on Ubuntu 18.04.1. The install works perfectly and my bash file is downloaded and executes but with errors.

Error message: "activation/ask does not exist". I tried troubleshooting this and reading the debconf dev configuration but can't really identify what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? Thanks

**EDIT:** If i go to shell during installation and wget, chmod this post.sh script, everything works just fine. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh

# Library to interact with debconf.
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

# Create the template file
cat > /tmp/activate.template <<EOL
Template: activation/title
Type: text
Description: Activate

Template: activation/ask
Type: string
Description: Enter Activation Code
EOL

# Load your template
debconf-loadtemplate activation /tmp/activate.template

# Set title for dialogue box
db_settitle activation/title

# Input activation code
db_input critical activation/ask
db_go

# Fetch input from user
db_get activation/ask

# Save it to a file
echo "$RET" > /root/answer.value

#Error message: activation/ask does not exist
```

The templates are renamed, so don't worry about the mismatch there. Thanks

[image: error]

Comment: I manually removed all whitespace and tried to remove all empty lines. And so there would be no doubt, "dos2unix post.sh". Still same problem. I'm using the "ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso (749,7 MB)" image, as the latest is using subiquity. But there might be some changes to this image and debconf?

Comment: I have the exact same problem on 16.04.5

Comment: I was unable to repro in a Docker instance running Xenial, though I got a different, unrelated error message. Is `activate` related to a package which exists locally?

Comment: No. Maybe i have misunderstood. I don't have a package at all. Just wanted to take a custom user input and save to file which will be available to use as an activation key for a http post for later. Thanks

Comment: Er, wait ... So you are setting up a fresh Ubuntu instance for each blog post?

Comment: Haha. No. May you share the code you used to take user input? I have gotten error code 127 earlier.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are doing here. I have only used preseed to set up new Ubuntu instances but this looks like maybe you are using it for something else entirely. Perhaps [edit] the question to explain what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I really just want to ask a user a custom question during install and save the value to a file. Anything besides that is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: The [manual page](https://www.mankier.com/1/debconf-loadtemplate) says *""**Warning:**
This program should never be used from a maintainer script of a package that uses debconf! It may however, be useful in debugging, or to seed the debconf database."* Could that be a clue?

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with how the script was executed.

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target /usr/bin/wget -O /root/post.sh http://<ip>/preseed/post.sh; \
in-target /bin/chmod +x /root/post.sh; \
in-target /bin/bash /root/post.sh
```